# How to position ads properly on a page that features a single image?

Tags: google-adsense, website-design, advertising, google-adsense-policies

I believe my AdSense account has been affected in some way since my CTR has dropped from 2.2% to 0.8% overnight.

I didn’t get any notification from Google on my AdSense or webmaster tools accounts warning me I was doing anything wrong, but after studying my reports and reading other threads on this forum I came to the conclusion I might have been placing ads too aggressively on one particular page template that my site uses a lot.

I have completely removed ads from that page template right now while I think how to place them better, and that’s where I would like to ask for the community help.

Below you can find a screenshot of the page template affected. It’s an image page template and therefore has little content which I know is not ideal… however my users browse tens of images for every “pure content” page that the look at, so I feel like not monetizing these pages would be a huge waste.

Now my question is, how many ads would you place on a page like this and where would you position them to make sure they are effective but at the same time are not too aggressive to Google’s eye?

[image]

Comment: Google relies on text-based content. without any of text on your site, you'll end up with trouble if you post ads anywhere on the page

Answer (score -1):

I don't think any ad need to necessary here. May be you can use one banner rectangle ad under file history. That also may help your ctr and cpm.

Comment: This answer is very short and not very helpful.   Can you edit it to expand it?   Linking to articles that explain when ads needed would be good.   It would also be good to explain how ad placement effects ctr and cpm.